# Can't figure out how I have to build my Docker architecture

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

So currently I'm building an API in PHP as different (micro) services which runs on nginx.

I've followed all the Docker fundamental video's and went through the docs, but I still can't figure out how to implement it.

- Do I need a server where I push my code to and deploy on the containers (with CI or so)?
- Does the container volume get pushed to the hub as well? So my code will be in the container itself?

Answer (score 0):

I think you messed up a bit what's container and what's an image. For me image is something you build on disk to run. And container is an image running on the computer and serving/doing things.

> Do I need a server where I push my code to and deploy on the containers

No, you don't. You start building image from some base image, and from a Dockerfile. So make some work dir, copy Dockerfile here, copy your PHP sources here as PHPAPI and in Dockerfile have commands to copy PHP into docker. Along the lines

```
FROM ubuntu:15.04
MAINTAINER guidsen

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y nginx && \
    apt-get install -y php && \
    apt-get autoremove; apt-get clean; apt-get autoclean

RUN mkdir -p /root/PHPAPI
COPY PHPAPI /root/PHPAPI

WORKDIR /root/PHPAPI
CMD /root/PHPAPI/main.php
```

> Does the container volume get pushed to the hub as well? So my code will be in the container itself?

That depends on what do you use to run containers from image. AWS I think require image pulled from Docker hub, so you have to push it here first. Some other cloud providers or private clouds require to push image directly to them. And yes, your code would be in the image and will be run in the container.

Comment: So every service will have nginx again? Isnt it better to have one nginx container and link that one to your services?

Comment: @guidsen that's the question I cannot answer, I have no idea about your desired architecture. Say, you want PHPAPI+nginx connecting to database. Good implementation would be image with PHP+nginx, another image with database engine, and another pure data image with db tables. When you run it, you'll get one container with OHO+nginx, several containers with databases and several data containers